# Stacktrace is missing methods when proguard obfuscation on

Tags: android, proguard, crashlytics

I noticed that on my Crashlytics/Fabric dashboard, for my proguard obfuscated release builds, I would be missing the first (and most important) method + line number of the stack trace. For my debug builds, I would be able to see this method properly.

So concretely, in my `onCreateView()` I call my `updateData()` method (where my crash was occurring) but in my obfuscated builds `updateData()` wasn't showing in the stacktrace, only the `onCreateView()`. Unobfuscated builds showed the proper stacktrace with both methods.

I'm using `proguard-android-optimize.txt` because I needed to remove Logs from my release build.

How do I get the proper stack track to show properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stacktrace is inconsistent because the `proguard-android-optimize.txt` configuration applies ALL optimizations except for the ones specified here (from `proguard-android-optimize.txt`):

`-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!code/simplification/cast,!field/*,!class/merging/*`

So how this reads is anything prepended with the `'!'` mark is an optimization that's excluded, but all other optimizations are included. Explained here: http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/optimizations.html

The reason methods were disappearing from the stack trace is one of the default optimizations is method inlining. So in our `proguard-rules.txt` file, we simple have to add this line in order to prevent that from happening:

`-optimizations !method/inlining/*`